# unable to access getter properly

Tags: java, exception

can some tell me what's wrong with my code?  even if I'm putting right password,unable to access balance with getBalance()... :(

```
package home.exercises.exceptionHandling;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Manager {

    private double balance = 15000.25;


        public void getBalance() throws InputMismatchException {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter password: ");

        String password = s.nextLine();

        if (password == "ManagerWantsTogetBalance") {

            System.out.println("Remainning balance is " + this.balance);    
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong password! Try Again..");
        }



    }

}



package home.exercises.exceptionHandling;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class TestManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Manager branchManager = new Manager();

        try {
            branchManager.getBalance();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException iex) {

            System.out.println("Put password in the correct form");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This post lacks of an example and a clear problem statement. You have to provide input example that shows that this code doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compare your `Strings` with `.equals()` function, never with `==`.

```
if("ManagerWantsTogetBalance".equals(password)){
  //Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
password == "ManagerWantsTogetBalance"
```

you should be using `equals` (or `equalsIgnoreCase` if you don't care about uppercase / lowercase differences) to compare two `String`s, because those methods check the actual contents.

The `==` operator instead checks whether the references to the objects are equal (they point to the same memory area).

For more information: [Java String.equals versus == [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 0):

When comparing String we use the .equals("Whatyouwanttocompare") method. So your if statement should look like 
    if(password.equals("ManagerWantsTo GetBalance")) { 
}
You use == to compare primitive datatype such as int and double etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator compares object references. So it returns true only if the operands are the **same** object. In the case of strings it would return true only if the objects are the same string. If you want to compare strings use the `equals` method. It returns true if the content of the strings is the same which is your desired behavior:

```
string1.equals(string2)
```